# Asserting Against Large Dynamic Response

Tags: karate

I have a very large response array I want to assert against, but without knowing the order.  I have a variable with the expected response values so I can do a single giant comparison, but I'm unable to load the entire response and compare it with the entire expected response variable at the same time.

```
* def obligationsQuery = Java.type("tests.account.sql.Obligations").getObligations(division, account)
    * def getObligations = db.readRows(obligationsQuery)

    Given path "account", "v1", "accounts", systemId, "obligations"
      And header api-key = gatewayKey
    When method GET
    Then status 200
      And match $.data != null
      And match $.data[*].transactionType contains any "<transactionTypeResponse>"
      And match $.data[*] contains only getObligations

    Examples:
      | description | transactionType | transactionTypeResponse |
      | Invoice     | 001             | invoice
```

The error I get is:

```
get_obligations_collection.feature:49 - path: $.data[*][*], actual: [{"object1"}, {"object2"}, {"etc"}], expected: {"object1"}, reason: actual value does not contain expected
```

I've also tried:
`And match each $.data[*] contains only getObligations`
But then I get:

```
get_obligations_collection.feature:49 - path: $[0], actual: [{"object1"}, expected: [{"object1"}, {"object2"}, {"etc"}, reason: actual value is not list-like
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that `contains only` would show the complete value of my variable, but smartly, it only shows the object that fails to match the api response object.  Was able to verify that through a simpler assert, and then checking the error message saw that an ID was missing padding that the API adds, but the DB does not.

As usual, just looking more closely at the data returned provides a simple explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `$.data` is a JSON array so no need to use json-path to again get the data into another array by calling as `$.data[*]`.

so,

`And match $.data contains only getObligations`

should work.

If this still not working, please provide some proper `response` and `getObligations` values to investigate further.

Comment: yep, Karate still handled `$.data[*]`, but you are correct, not needed.